# Multiple ways of finding Big O of a function

Tags: big-o, computer-science

I'm struggling with understanding Big O and I'm unable to quite comprehend the multiple ways that I read, and watch, that are used to find the Big O of a function. It seems that every video or post has a slightly different way of doing it.

Some: Count the operations line by line.
Others, count assignments, multiplications, and additions.

I know this question might be downvoted/closed but I feel I really need an answer specifically to my questions in order to completely understand it.

In this psuedocode taken from https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQeQH.png

```
function sum(list):
    sum = 0;
    foreach element in list:
        current = element
        add current to sum
    sum = sum * 1
    return sum
endfunction
```

The author states that the time is `1 + n * 2 + 2` because `it sets sum to 0, which takes one operation`, `it iterates over the list, performing two operations each time`, and `then, it performs two more operations`.

I don't necessarily see how the author gets two operations, instead of 3, that is... `current = element` is one operation, and, in my opinion, `add current to sum` is two operations (assignment and addition). As well as, `sum = sum * 1` the author states this to be one operation, but I believe it to be two, and `return sum` another operation. Thus, the time should be `1 + n * 3 + 3`.

If anyone could please tell me if I am not understanding why this should be two operations, or if it i really three?

Also, from reading I've noticed most people dont tend to include comparison as an operation. Is it alright to ommit comparison?

And finally, the page at http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic780601.files/time_analysis_matrix_multiplication.pdf seems to be the most helpful reference I've found, but they calculate the Big O a totally different way. They calculate the additions, multiplications, and assignments (again ommoting comparisons) and then add them together.

For the code:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { 
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
        c[i][j] = 0;
        for ( int k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; 
        } 
    }
}
```

It says `n^3 multiplications`... `2n^3 + n^2 + n additions`... `n^3 + 2n^2 + n + 1` assignments...

Removing coefficients and all but the largest term:

It says

`O(n^3) multiplications + O(n^3) additions + O(n^3) assignments = O(n^3) overall time complexity.` 

When adding these, is it technically `n^3 + n^3 + n^3 = 3n^3` and removing coefficients, this leaves us with `n^3`? I am asking because I don't see how mathematically `n^3 + n^3 + n^3 = n^3`.

The way I've found it most helpful to do it is how the page at harvard does it: Counting additions, multiplications, and assignments. I was wondering if there are many ways to do it, and if this is one way that would yield the correct answer every time? This is because for the first psuedocode example, the equation we get would be different (pre removing coefficients and all but largest term).

So if I were to do to the first psuedocode example the way that it's done in the harvard document, I would get:

`Multiplications: sum * 1... happens 1 time.`
`Additions: add current to sum, happens n times.`
`Assignments: sum = 0... happens 1 time. current = element, happens n times... add current to sum... happens n times.`
`1 multiplication + n additions + 1 + n + n assignments = 2 + 3n`
`Removing coefficients and all  but largest term: O(n)`.

Note that I didn't include the return statement in the equation, and i also didn't include the addition that happens n times when element is incremented. Really, I don't know exactly what I need to keep and what I need to discard.

Could someone please tell me how I would be able to do the above, but be correct? What should I ommit, and what should I keep? And What is the easiest way to find the Big O? Like in the first example, like in the harvard example, or another way? I feel like I can relate best to the harvard example, however, I need to know what the rules are when doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please accept an answer or provide feedback so this question can be completed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

O (n^3) doesn't mean n^3 operations: It means the number of operations is less than some unknown constant times n^3. Therefore O (n^3) + O (n^3) = O (n^3): The first is less than some constant times n^3, the second is less than some constant times n^3, and if you add them, the sum is less than some (larger) constant times n^3.